# Compute the limit $\lim\limits_{z \to 1 \\ |z| \lt 1} (1-z) \exp \left (\frac {z+1} {z-1} \right ).$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Compute the limit $$\lim\limits_{z \to 1 \\ |z| \lt 1} (1-z) \exp \left (\frac {z+1} {z-1} \right ).$$

By taking modulus I find that it is bounded by $|1-z| \frac {|1+z|^2} {1 - |z|^2}.$ So can we somehow conclude that $\frac {|1-z|} {1 - |z|^2}$ goes to some limit as $z$ approaches $1\ $? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ArielFishbein$:$ You have to deal with $\frac {1} {\frac {1 - |z|} {|1-z|}}$ when $z \to 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\exp (\frac {z+1} {z-1})|=\exp [ \Re (\frac {z+1} {z-1})] $ and $\Re (\frac {z+1} {z-1})=\Re [ (z+1)(\overline z -1)]/|z-1|^{2}] <0$ for $|z|<1$. Hence, $\exp (\frac {z+1} {z-1})$ is bounded and the required limit is $0$.

$\Re z$ stands for the real part of $z$.

Comment: What does $\Re$ Mean

Comment: $\Re z$ stands for the real part of $z$. @ArielFishbein

Comment: Good observation @geetha290krm. I didn't expand it out. That's the reason I missed the trick. Thanks a lot.